# Forms Authentication with roles using GenericPrincipal: Problems with jQuery.cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, jquery-cookie

I want to use rule based authentication and authorization like this:

### UserController:

```
string roles = "edit,admin";
var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(30), user.RememberMe, roles, "/");
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

### Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
        GenericPrincipal userPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name), roles);
        Context.User = userPrincipal;
    }
}
```

Then I can use the Attribute `[Authorize(Roles = "edit")]` to limit access.
**This works just fine!**

### Now to the actual problem:

I use jQuery-Cookie in some JS-Files and I am **unable to overwrite old cookies**. This worked before but now everytime I call this code **instead of overwriting** the old cookie **a new cookie with the same name and path** is created.

```
$.cookie("grid_filter_data", $grid[0].p.postData.filters, { expires: 365, path: "/" });
```

Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant to your problem, but I believe forms authentication cookies are HttpOnly <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.httponly.aspx"></a>, and so inaccessible to client script on recent browsers.

Comment: I don't want to access the cookies that forms auth sets, I use different cookies with $.cookie.

Comment: OK, this seems to be a false alarm, there are no multiple cookies created, my Firefox just shows multiple cookies each time the value changes. When I select "Settings/Privacy/Show Cookies" I get this behaviour. Firebug only shows one cookie. So does Google Chrome.
But FF behaved differently last week... maybe I changed a setting or so...